# Building tensorflow from source fails during pip package install

Tags: tensorflow, pip, python-wheel

After building TensorFlow from source, following https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source, the final step:

```
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
```

fails with:

```
ERROR: tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

If using verbose `-v` flag during the `pip` command I get:

> Using pip 21.0.1 from /Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
> Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
> Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-kcizkayy
> Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ohydypwq
> Initialized build tracking at /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ohydypwq
> Created build tracker: /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ohydypwq
> Entered build tracker: /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ohydypwq
> Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-install-euaz0ym2
>
> ERROR: tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
>
> Exception information:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
> status = self.run(options, args)
> File "/Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)
> File "/Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 316, in run
> requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
> File "/Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 100, in resolve
> r = self.factory.make_requirement_from_install_req(
> File "/Users/opprud/PycharmProjects/edgeimpulse/tf_source/venv_py/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 300, in make_requirement_from_install_req
> raise UnsupportedWheel(msg)
> pip._internal.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
>
> Removed build tracker: '/private/var/folders/q8/fw6l6q893fq826p462f5jbt40000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ohydypwq'

The command `./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg` seems to build a pip wheel for **macosx_11_0** while my macOS is version **11.1**

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this, but I can show you why this is happening: Running `build_pip_package` executes [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.sh#L246) which runs the `bdist_wheel` command. This will search your system for the type of platform via `distutils.util.get_platform()` and then [try to format](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blob/master/src/wheel/bdist_wheel.py#L52) this tag.

Comment: (cont) if the major version is > 10, it replaces the [minor version with `0`](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blob/41b375ef33e3368f6f58c13f9649491d01c2ba5e/src/wheel/macosx_libfile.py#L368)

Comment: A fix, but not a solution for me was to rename the wheel from `ensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl` to `tensorflow-2.5.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`